# Putting a newline character between the strings in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have queries

```sql
select 'Hello' || chr(13) ||' world' as new from dual;
select 'Hello' || chr(10) ||' world' as new from dual;
```

both giving me result as Hello World, but I want to print it like,

Hello 
World

Can I please get help with this? It is basically putting a newline character between the strings.

Comment: Your apporach is correct - but it is relevant where on which environment the query result is displayed. Especially GUIs seem to eat the new lines.

Comment: Executing the query in SQL Developer

Comment: In that case, select your query and execute it with F5.

Comment: @René Nyffenegger So we don't execute like normally we do ? Why Ctrl +Enter (Run statement) doesn't work but F5 (Run Script) does?

Comment: If executed with ctrl-enter, you can click (or double click?) on the cell in the result which opens a popup where you see the line break.

Comment: @René Nyffenegger  Okay ya got it Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It should work for you.

```
select 'Hello' || chr(13) || chr(10)||' world' from dual
```

Chr(10) =  line feed

Chr(13) =  carriage return

Comment: It's still giving Hello World

Comment: You can use both chr(13)||chr(10)

Comment: Nopes still same

Comment: On which environment are you running ?

Comment: In Sql Developer.

Comment: It works as intended, but tool you use (SQL Developer, as you say) doesn't display it properly. Double-click the result, then click the pencil button on the right hand side of the field and you'll see a pop-up window which displays it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a literal newline.

```
SELECT 'Hello
World!' FROM DUAL;
```

```
'HELLOWORLD!'
*************
Hello
World!
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7f6abf65e94421f75290de4d88b12603)*

Comment: This is the same string, although formulated differently, and will be shown in one line in SQL Developer as well.